# What kind of coordinate system has values like 48569.800mE, 706602.032mN?

Tags: coordinate-system

I am seeing the following set of coordinates, and I was wondering what kind of system is this?

`48569.800mE, 706602.032mN`

Comment: Could be almost any projected coordinate system, do you have any more information about it?

Comment: The Easting value is very small (too small, really) to be a UTM, MGA (Australia), or Gauss-Krueger zone. As @MichaelMiles-Stimson asked, do you know what location the coordinates represent?

Answer (score 1):

It is UTM co-ordinate system. It should be with proper zone number and north/South hemisphere. e.g See image:

[image]

Comment: The easting value is too small to be UTM. If it is UTM, the position is outside the "base" zone. That is, it's 4 degrees west of the central meridian (and 6.37 degrees north of the equator).

Comment: Yes, the value of the easting is less than the *false easting* of 50000 which is used for UTM (and MGA) - It really should be in the next zone west but that's no good if you're comparing it against features in the same zone. If you had an idea roughly where it is you can usually work it out, like is it north or south of the equator? Is it near Dalby (MGA55) or Broome (MGA51)... those sorts of things will lead you to what zone it's likely to be then if it doesn't line up with known landmarks it's bound to be Albers or Lamberts - contact the vendor!

Answer (score 0):

With the additional detail you gave in your other (meanwhile deleted) question it should be in Nigeria near Lagos.

According to http://www.asprs.org/a/resources/grids/02-2009-nigeria.pdf, before switching to UTM, a CRS based at Minna named Modified Transverse Mercator was used in Nigeria.

Available EPSG codes are:

```
EPSG:26391 Minna West Belt
EPSG:26392 Minna Mid Belt
EPSG:26393 Minna East Belt
EPSG:26331 Minna UTM 31N
EPSG:26332 Minna UTM 32N
```

Minna East/Mid/West Belt do not fit, the coordinates end up in neighbouring Benin. My best guess would be UTM 32N, but the resulting point is actually within the 31N zone, 171km East of Lagos:

[image]